# Lubuntu/Windows 10 dual-boot always loads into grub rescue?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, windows-10

I have an HP Stream that is virtually worthless as a laptop because it only has a 20 GB hard drive, so I installed Lubuntu on it so that I could at least use it for watching videos or writing a quick email.

Anyway, when I first installed it the boot worked perfectly fine, but now whenever I boot up the laptop, it **only** boots into grub-rescue. When I try to load Lubuntu using grub recovery steps, it says my ext3 partition cannot be identified. *However,* I can load into Lubuntu/Windows by doing the following steps:

1. Press ESC at boot to trigger the BIOS menu.
2. Open the boot menu.
3. Choose the Ubuntu boot loader or Windows boot loader. This menu is created by the BIOS.

Also worth mentioning that Lubuntu files are on a micro-USB that's always plugged into the laptop, so maybe that has something to do with it.

Why would Grub be unable to boot my Lubuntu installation, but my BIOS can?

Comment: You're rather unclear with specific details; I don't know what Lubuntu release, and specifically where exactly your installed your system to, and what changes you've made (esp. to BIOS/settings on the device) since install. The grub/boot settings used at install may have been changed by a user in BIOS/config device settings which would explain your issue.  For specific help I suggest reading your messages; as booting to grub-rescue is the effect & the reason is usually on-screen... alternatively boot a *live* system & check for issues (file-system checks etc that can cause boot issues)